# Kinect "no device connected" error in openni.launch after openni-dev package upgrade

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using turtlebot on ROS electric on ubuntu 11.04.

The openni-dev package was recently updated from version 1.1.0.41~natty to 1.3.2.1-4~natty2.
After this update, the openni.launch process gives the error "No device connected.. Waiting for devices to be connected". Its not able to initialize.

I tried to downgrade the openni-dev version using the command:
"sudo apt-get install openni-dev=1.1.0.41~natty", but it says that the version was not found. I have also tried replacing the entries in the source.list files for apt to "old-releases.ubuntu.com", but it still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139001/kinect-%22no-device-connected%22-error-in-openni.launch-after-openni-dev-package-upgrade/) by [Brijendra Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6358/brijendra-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-05-14**:
You should be aware that ROS electric is quite old and a lot of the packages deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved the issue by un-installing the openni-dev package, which also removed the dependencies - nite-dev, ps-engine,  ros-electric-turtlebot, ros-electric-turtlebot-desktop, ros-electric-turtlebot-robot, ros-electric-turtlebot-viz, ros-electric-openni-kinect. And then re-installing these packages.

The openni.launch process is working fine now.

---

Originally posted by [Brijendra Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6358/brijendra-singh/) with karma: 68 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xianke](https://answers.ros.org/users/26399/xianke/) on 2016-03-26**:
Can you tell me how you solve it in detals?please.